# what is a $G$-invariant subgroup of a $p$-group?

Tags: terminology, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group. I have come cross the terminology:$G$-invariant subgroup. I can't find the definition of it. Is it same as invariant subgroup?
(The invariant subgroup is normal subgroup.)
Thanks!

Comment: Usually the term "$G$-invariant" requires something with an action of $G$. So yes, it probably just means normal subgroup, since the only natural way to have $G$ act on itself is by conjugation.

Comment: Do you mean, if there is an action of $G$ and $K$ is a $G$-invariant subgroup,then $K$ is invariant subgroup of $G$ over this action? And if the action of $G$ is obvious,usually conjugation,then the $G$-invariant subgroup is just the normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: I mean that the term needs more context usually, but since there is a natural choice of action, that is probably the one meant here.